# jQuery fetching extra content through starfish and google domains ? Why?

Tags: jquery, cdn

jQuery recommends CDN hosted or self hosted jQuery library.
Here is the download path of minified version :
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js

I deployed the same to my cdn,and used it in my website.
However for both, my CDN path , or the above mentioned jQuery path, the script makes
http calls starfish, google domain to download more content :

[image]

1. Why are these components being downloaded,is there anything incorrect in my method of using jQuery ?
2. Are these components compulsory ?
3. If these are optional components, can I configure jQuery in a way to not download these components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get these extra requests. This leads me to believe that it is your browser that's making these extra requests, not the script.

Perhaps it is your Firefox extensions? Try disabling them, restart Firefox and try again (you're use Firebug to make the checks, so you'll have to leave that enabled, I've not seen Firebug make these requests on its own before).

Comment: Thanks.Will try in safe mode of the browser.

Comment: Can you please share firebug requests log of opening this url : http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js ? Do you get only 1 request ?

Comment: thanks. I will try to figure out what might be triggering this.I also see only jQuery in chrome. So, some firefox extension might be the culprit.

Comment: A firefox addon was doing those requests.

Answer (score 2):

Loading jQuery does not trigger any further HTTP requests on its own. If you're seeing other requests, they're coming from something else, not from jQuery.